# How to check for any keypress if python terminal is focused in

Tags: python, terminal, console, focus, keypress

How would I check if the python terminal is focused in when making a keypress. I know about msvcrt, but I want to do custom keypress combinations and stuff like that which msvcrt simply can't do. I know about other modules that can detect a keypress but they work even if you aren't focused into the terminal. Checking if the window is the console could work, but it wouldn't if you were using the vscode terminal, for example. I want it to be when you are focused in the terminal, not the window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if the console application has the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71402456/check-if-the-console-application-has-the-focus)