# Check if the console application has the focus

Tags: python, windows, focus

I'm working on a Python console app.
I want to check if the focus is on the console of my application.
I can assume my code will be executed on a Windows PC.
The use case is to activate or not the hotkeys.
So maybe I am facing an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).
At the moment I'm using this unsafe version:

```
import win32gui

# Before the execution starts, I assume the focus will be on the console
CURRENT_CONSOLE = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

def is_console_on_focus():
    # Check whether the console has the focus
    return win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() == CURRENT_CONSOLE:

def hotkey_method():
    if not is_console_on_focus():
        return
    ...

keyboard.add_hotkey('up arrow', hotkey_method)
```

The obvious problem is that the user can change the focus before the execution arrives to the row that defines `CURRENT_CONSOLE`.

There is another problem:
If I'm debugging Visual Code with the integrated console, my method cannot tell whether the focus is on the console or somewhere else in the Visual Code window (for example on the code).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import win32gui,win32process,os

focus_window_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())[1]
current_process_pid = os.getppid()

print(focus_window_pid == current_process_pid )
```

`win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())[1]` will get the parent process pid, so we need to use `os.getppid()` to get the parent pid of python process.

But if you are using other method to run your python script(eg: vscode), this method may not work.

Comment: Indeed when I run the code it works and when I run it with VC it doesn't.
For those wondering, in VC it doesn't work whether I use the integrated console or the external console.